# menu hover over not working on windows 8 phone and windows surface

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8

On my web site, I have css that allows me to hover over a main menu item (like in my case "About" and have the submenu (list items) appear. It works on iphone,android,chrome,safari,IE windows 8.1 but not on windows 8 phone and windows surface.  The CSS that gets hit I believe is this:

```
#header .menuUserBar .menuWrap > ul > li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

You can see it live at the site http://www.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/

If there is some special attribute I need to make it recognize those problem browsers, please let me know that. Obviously, I'm not a css wizard, not even sure if I have risen to newby status yet.

Answer (score 6):

found answer:

```
 <a href="#" aria-haspopup="true"  ><span class="imgWrap"></span>
                    <h2>ABOUT</h2>
 </a>
```

aria-haspopup="true"

Comment: I'm glad you found this solution, but I don't totally understand why it's necessary. It looks like the aria-haspopup is a way of creating the touch scenario on IE10 in Windows 8 (and it looks like it applies to WP8 as well). There's a good article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj152135(v=vs.85).aspx about it. I guess the other browsers and then IE11 just enable this scenario automatically (or perhaps default to it).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I now have to deal with my menu not working in IE8. I'm not sure i should worry. IE8 seems to be 10% of the internet and 1% of my visitors.  I'm guessing I don't really care about the 1% as they are probably not code camp targets.

Answer (score 1):

This is weak design on the Windows Phone 8 IE Design team's part.  Tap & Hold translate into a right click instead of Hover - which was how Windows Mobile had translated it.

A 2 finger ([1x Tap Hold] + [1xTap]) could easily be used as a right click.

My biggest concern is that the newer design team members have completely broken the previous interaction method and have not replaced this with anything functional.

Providing us with a developer's discussion about how sites need to be edited to allow for "aria-haspopup" is silly since the problem is not a developer's problem but a user experience problem at the IE level.

This is a **IE** design team problem that is pushing users away from the Windows Phone 8 devices.

FIRE all incompetent developers who make excuses and replace them with people who understand the users needs and know not to break an experience that has worked for over a decade & who will know how simple providing hover functionality is.